# Android App making "application not responding" error example

Tags: android

I want to generate the "Application Not Responding" error on purpose.
Instead of ANR dialog, my sample app is working OK. Could you let me know how to generate ANR?

My test code is as follows.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dd);
        int k=0;
        // next part takes long time --> expecting ANR
        for(int i=0; i<9999; i++)  
            for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
                for(int jj=0; jj<100; jj++)
                k=i*j*j;
        tt.setText("OUT");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make an infinite `while` `loop` on `onClick()` event of a button so that your application is not responsive to any user input for after clicking that button.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void fun(View v) {
    while(true) {
        //Nothing to do
    }
}
```